# sorting integers in lists into bins

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of integers called shoesizes and quantities. The integers in the shoesizes list act like bins which have a quantity (in the same index) in the quantities list. I want to reorganise the lists so that I have the shoesizes in ascending order with all the quantities for each shoesize summed together.

```
shoesizes    = [ 2 ,  5 ,  6 , 1 , 3 , 2 ,  4 ,  5 , 2 , 3 , 1 ]    
quantities   = [ 50, 100, 120, 20, 40, 10, 90 , 10 ,30 , 20, 80]
```

So the desired output would be:

```
orderedsizes = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,  6 ]
totalquant   = [100, 90, 60, 90,110, 120]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to sort anyway, [`itertools.groupby` can be used to do this pretty nicely](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

shoesizes    = [ 2 ,  5 ,  6 , 1 , 3 , 2 ,  4 ,  5 , 2 , 3 , 1 ]    
quantities   = [ 50, 100, 120, 20, 40, 10, 90 , 10 ,30 , 20, 80]

# For convenience, short names for itemgetters
getsize, getcnt = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)

# Sort to bins of same size next to each other
sorted_bins = sorted(zip(shoesizes, quantities), key=getsize)

# Group and sum bins of same size
summed_sizes = [(k, sum(map(getcnt, g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted_bins, key=getsize)]

# Convert back to separate lists
orderedsizes, totalquant = map(list, zip(*summed_sizes))

print(orderedsizes)
print(totalquant)
```

Which outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[100, 90, 60, 90, 110, 120]
```

It's also possible to do this with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (or just `collections.defaultdict(int)`), then sorting the `.items()` of the `Counter`; unless the number of bins is huge, the performance differences are unlikely to matter; if you didn't want to sort in the first place though, `Counter` makes more sense by avoiding the sort entirely. Example code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

size_counts = defaultdict(int)
for size, cnt in zip(shoesizes, quantities):
    size_counts[size] += cnt

orderedsizes, totalquant = map(list, zip(*sorted(size_counts.items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a dictionary-like structure with duplicate keys. I would accumulate the values like so:

```
# ordersizes is just the set of unique size values in a list: sorted(list(set(shoesizes)))

[sum(v for key, v in zip(shoesizes, quantities) if key == index) for index in orderedsizes]
```

Comment: Why turn an approximately `O(n)` to `O(n log n)` (depending on whether you sort first then group or group in a `dict` then sort, and how much cutdown you get by grouping) algorithm into a `O(n**2)` algorithm when you don't need to? I mean yes, you can two-line it this way, but to what end? Also, side-note: `sorted(list(set(shoesizes)))` is redundantly converting to `list`; `sorted` already does that, so drop the `list` constructor and just use `sorted(set(shoesizes))`.